# Recalculate value from one range to other

Tags: algorithm, math, numbers, mapping, intervals

first of all let me introduce you to the problem.

Let's say that we have one sensor that is measuring something, tank oil/water level etc.
Sensor is calibrated for taking measurements from 0-3.5 [m].
According to that, we recieve feedback in percentage from 0 to 100 %.

Now, let's say that instead 0 [m] being my zero, we want that 1,2 [m] is 0%, and respectively 2,4 [m] to be 100%.

First thing I did is to calculate how much are values of 1,2 [m] and 2,4 [m] in original scale.

**1,2[m] -> 34.2% and 2,4[m] -> 68,4%**

So value of 34.2% on the original scale corresponds to 0% on new scale.
Value of 68.4% on the original scale corresponds to 100% on new scale.

Now if I want to rescale the original scale to be between these two values, how would you do it?
I suspect next step is substituing new "zero" (34,2 %) from measured value, and then I would need to map first one to other one, or other one to first one...something like that.

Thanks in advance!! Sorry if it is not clear, I tried to be clear as much as possible with problem.

---

P.S. Solution is appreciated, but I am looking forward to hearing explanation, this would be better.

Comment: You want the output to be a percentage or an absolute value?

Comment: It is not clear to me what you mean with rescaling. If the original feedback is 0%, what do you want it to be converted to?

Comment: @trincot Percentage. So for example, if original feedback is 34,8%, I want that it is 0% in my new scale/interval however you want to call it.
If original feedback is 68,4 % in my new scale I want it to be 100%. 
If it is 0% in original feedback, I think it should be -100% in new one.

Answer (score 1):

First, let's give names to these values.

The original height range is:

```
Hmin_0 = 0[m], Hmax_0 = 3.5[m]
```

The new height range is:

```
Hmin_1 = 1.2[m], Hmax_1 = 2.4[m]
```

Let's call x the sensor's output. We have:

```
x(h=0[m])=0 %
x(h=3.5[m])=100 %
```

Let's call x0 and x1 the sensor's reading for h = Hmin_1 and h = Hmax_1 respectively:

```
x0=Hmin_1/(Hmax_0-Hmin_0)*100   [%]
x1=Hmax_1/(Hmax_0-Hmin_0)*100   [%]
```

We are looking for a function f(x)=a*x+b such that:

```
f(x0) = 0
f(x1) = 100
```

You can check that the function:

```
f(x)=(x-x0)/(x1-x0)*100 (equ.1)
```

is the one you are looking for. Indeed, f(x0)=0 and f(x1)=100 as required.

Or, if you're not convinced, you can solve the system of 2 linear equations:

```
a * x0 + b = 0   (equ. 2)
a * x1 + b = 100 (equ. 3)
```

which will give:

```
a=100/(x1-x0) 
b=-x0*100/(x1-x0).
```

Regards

Answer (score 0):

> Sensor is calibrated for taking measurements from 0-3.5 [m].

Let `max = 3.5`

> we receive feedback in percentage from 0 to 100 %.

Let's call it `feedback`

> we want that 1.2 [m] is 0%, and respectively 2.4 [m] to be 100%.

Let `low = 1.2` and `high = 2.4`

Then the mapping can be derived as follows:

First convert `feedback` to the original absolute measure, i.e. `max * feedback/100`

Then subtract `low` so to make sure that an absolute value of `low` maps to 0.

Then apply a coeficient so that the absolute distance of `high - low` maps to 100. That coefficient is thus `100 / (high - low)`.

That's it. The final formula is thus:

```
(max * feedback / 100 - low) * 100 / (high - low)
```

Or equivalent:

```
(max * feedback - low * 100) / (high - low)
```

Here is a JavaScript snippet that makes this conversion for feedback in [0, 10, 20, ..., 100]:

```js
let max = 3.5;
let low = 1.2;
let high = 2.4;

for (let feedback = 0; feedback <= 100; feedback += 10) {
    let output = (max * feedback - low * 100) / (high - low);
    console.log(feedback, "=>", output);
}
```